# How to Get Output using CodeDomProvider?

Tags: c#, .net

I can use CodeDomProvider for compiling the C# Code. I compiled and got the compiled result. But I want to get the output of the code snippet below. How do i get this?

e.g.:

```
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

The above code is what i am using. I can successfully compile it but did not get the result. How can I get the result?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can compile and get the results too. 
You need to have your code under namespace and within a function

```
CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);

Assembly assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
Type program = assembly.GetType("Dynamic.Test");
MethodInfo main = program.GetMethod("Test");
main.Invoke(null, null);
```

Above Summary from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saf5ce06(v=vs.100).aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime

**EDIT-**

Created below program with some modifications to read result. Hope this helps.

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string code = @"
                            using System;
                            using System.Collections.Generic;

                            namespace Dynamic1
                            {
                                public class Test
                                {
                                    public static IEnumerable<int> Test1()
                                    {
                                       for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
                                        {
                                            yield return i;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ";
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            CompilerParameters parameters =new CompilerParameters();
            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);
            Assembly assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
            Type program = assembly.GetType("Dynamic1.Test");
            MethodInfo main = program.GetMethod("Test1");
            IEnumerable<int> outputResults = (IEnumerable<int>)main.Invoke(null, null);
            foreach (var result in outputResults)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```